# Why chakra ui toast is not showing on react-query useQuery success?

Tags: reactjs, react-query, chakra-ui

I am using react-query. On Successful completion of a query I want a toast to appear with an appropriate message. I am using chakra UI toast.

Here is the code:

```
import { useToast } from "@chakra-ui/react";

export const useBookmark = () => {
    const queryClient = useQueryClient();
    const toast = useToast();

    const { mutate: handleDelete } = useMutation((postId: string) => deleteBookmark(postId), {
        onSuccess: (data) => {
            console.log(data);
            toast({ title: "Bookmark deleted", status: "success", duration: 3000, isClosable: true });
            queryClient.invalidateQueries("bookmark");
        },
        onError: (error) => {
            console.log(error);
        },
    });

    

    return { handleDelete };
};
```

I want a toast to appear when the query is run successfully, but the toast is not showing up. Please guide me.

Comment: Could you please provide a codesandbox about this code, so that others can debug better and support faster. I try to reproduce your problem but I got error related to the libraries in the node_modules.